# Unable to return a value from Tkinter Entry box - need to pass an entry value from one script to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm just about ready to pull my hair out - have tried just about everything I can imagine to do something that on the face of it seems fairly simple...

I need to have an Entry box, which takes in a variable, which is returned to the code and can be used as a variable throughout the script. I actually need to import this script and use it in the code of another script.

At the moment, I know the Submit button is calling the get_data() function, because using 'print' displays the password entered. But using return, to return it to the parent function, and then returning that value and printing the output of the main function returns nothing.

Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

def get_params():

    def get_data():
        pw = pwentry_enter.get()
        return pw

    window = Tk()

    headFrame = Frame(window)
    headFrame.grid(row=0, pady=6)
    header = Label(headFrame, text="Input Password", font=(f1, 20))
    header.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
    mainFrame = Frame(window, bg="#1B2230")
    mainFrame.grid(row=1, pady=6)

    raw_password = StringVar()
    pwentry_enter=Entry(mainFrame, width=30, font=(f2,10), show="*", textvariable=raw_password)
    pwentry_enter.pack()

    btnFrame = Frame(window)
    btnFrame.grid(row=2, pady=6)

    submit_btn = Button(btnFrame, text='Submit', command=get_data, width=10, bg="#DB4158", fg="black", font=(f2, 20))
    submit_btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
    quit_btn = Button(btnFrame, text='Quit', command=window.destroy, width=10, bg="#DB4158", fg="black", font=(f2, 20))
    quit_btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

    window.mainloop()

    a = get_data()
    return a
```

Comment: can you tell in which line you are printing the password.
`a = get_data()` will execute after the window is destroyed.

Comment: If I change 'return pw' to print(pw), and if I print(get_params()) at the end, the password is outputted.

Comment: That is printing because you are calling the function when you click submit button.

Comment: Indeed, but I need it returned, so that I can pass it to another script. I can't manipulate or display it in any way, without printing it, which isn't very helpful to me.

Comment: Don't add return in `get_data()` and use a global variable to store the password when submit button is clicked and return when quit button is pressed.
Refer the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add return in get_data() and use a global variable to store the password when submit button is clicked and return when quit button is pressed.
You are trying to read data of the Entry after destroying the window.

```
from tkinter import *

pw = ''
def get_params():
    global pw
    def get_data():
        global pw
        pw = pwentry_enter.get()

    window = Tk()

    headFrame = Frame(window)
    headFrame.grid(row=0, pady=6)
    header = Label(headFrame, text="Input Password", font=(f1, 20))
    header.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
    mainFrame = Frame(window, bg="#1B2230")
    mainFrame.grid(row=1, pady=6)

    raw_password = StringVar()
    pwentry_enter=Entry(mainFrame, width=30, font=(f2,10), show="*", textvariable=raw_password)
    pwentry_enter.pack()

    btnFrame = Frame(window)
    btnFrame.grid(row=2, pady=6)

    submit_btn = Button(btnFrame, text='Submit', command=get_data, width=10, bg="#DB4158", fg="black", font=(f2, 20))
    submit_btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
    quit_btn = Button(btnFrame, text='Quit', command=window.destroy, width=10, bg="#DB4158", fg="black", font=(f2, 20))
    quit_btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

    window.mainloop()

    return pw
```

Comment: That works perfectly - thanks so much! So it was the lack of global declaration?

Comment: Not only because of global declaration, you were trying to read the data of entry after destroying the window.
Don't know why it was not causing error when you were executing the program

Comment: This answer would be better if it included a description of what you added, removed, or changed. Otherwise we have to compare the code line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you've changed.